# How do I: Save form information in the form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, web

This is my sample form script:

```
<body bgcolor="silver">
<center>
<form method="POST">
<h1><u>Updates/Ideas for Server</u></h1><br>
<br>
<textarea name="fileData" rows=25 cols=60>
</textarea><br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Update" name="submit">
</form>
</br>
<h1><u>Finished List</u></h1><br>
<br />-example 1
<br />-example 2
<br />-example 3
</center>
</body>
```

I need to know how to make the form information save into the form itself so I can keep coming back to it whenever I want and make changes.

Note: The 2nd part, "Finished List" is going to be edited in HTML, and is not part of my question.

Thank you,
~Aaron

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use some kind of server technology to enable this, or use localstorage.

Comment: Have you any experience in programming/scripting?  What kind of webserver are you running?

Comment: I do have experience, I just don't know how to make it save in the form. I'm running it off of Godaddy.

Comment: Ok, so what kind of server technology are you running?  ASP/PHP?  You would need to know how to use these to save, or to use localstorage as shown by @WithoutATowel

Comment: Ok.  Do you know anything about using PHP?  What level of experience are you at?

Comment: I'm very familiar with it, I've just never tried anything like this. I've developed several websites in php.

Comment: In that case I'm unable to help you.  My knowledge of php is limited, but in general the process you need is this.  When the webpage is opened, you'll need to query a database to see if the current user has previously completed the form.  If so, then display the last values.  When the user clicks submit, then save the form values to the same database.  If you've experienced developing using php, this shouldn't be too tricky to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

It would be overkill to use a database, assuming you're showing us the full form (and not just a stripped down example). Use localstorage:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage

Comment: It might depend on whether the user would return to the form from a different machine or not.  Localstorage would not solve this issue.

Comment: This wouldn't work for me. Several different people have to access this form to add/edit information.

Comment: In that case you need to utilise whatever server technology your website is built on.  Without that, you're stuck with a form on a webpage, unfortunately.